# tkinter Treeview insert element having multiple parents

Tags: python, tkinter, insert, treeview

I am trying to insert an element having more than one parent into a tree. Currently to insert an element having one parent I am using this:

```
tree.insert(nodeParent,1,nodeName,text = nodeName,values=description)
```

Is there a way to update this inserted element and make it a child of another element/Once it is inserted how do I make it a child of an more than one elements?

For example if I have elements: "Data Science" and "Data Engineering" in a tree and I want to insert an element "Data" under both these elements how would I do that?I am currently doing this, but get an error : element "Data" already exists

```
tree.insert(Data Science,1,Data,text = "Data",values=description)
tree.insert(Data Engineering,Data, text="Data",values=description)
```